# Custom field in JIRA derived from existing fields

Tags: jira, customization

Is it possible to have a custom field that's derived from existing fields.
In my case I have a field `Aha Ref` that points to a URL and I'd like a new field `AhaLinked` whose value should be a boolean `Aha Ref != null`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins that will support dynamic custom fields. ScriptRunner and Power Custom Fields PRO are two that will support this. You can't do it in standard Jira custom fields

Answer (score 0):

Yep, if you do not want to pay a plugin license fee, then create your own realization of custom field by developing your own plugin.